Backtesting.py Indicators Optimization
In the past 15 days, I have watched Mr. Chad Thackray's playlist on YouTube twice and read the Backtesting.py API Reference Documentation. I primarily work with dictionaries because I find NumPy and pandas a bit complicated, so my experience is working on dictionaries.
So far, I have solved many problems and successfully integrated my strategy into Backtesting.py. However, I am currently facing a final issue that I have tried to resolve in every possible way, but I still cannot solve it.
Functions
prepare()
Initializes the data for Backtesting.py.
ohlc()
Retrieves chart data.
indicators()
Obtains analysis data.
TestAnalytics.start()
Initializes the main analytics core.
TestAnalytics.run()

Retrieves live data or data from a CSV file.
Applies strategies and indicators.
Saves the processed data in data.csv and returns it.

data.csv Preview



time
low
high
open
close
volume
spread
type
pattern
high_tail
low_tail
tails
body
diff
all
fair_value_gap
support_and_resistance
market_structure_shift
break_of_structure
rsi
sma
signal_buy
signal_sell
signal_neutral
action
stop_loss
limit_price
take_profit
tp_pip
sl_pip




1698105600
1.06609
1.06734
1.06686
1.06721
4693
1













1.06436











1698134400
1.06439
1.06947
1.06789
1.06501
17555
0









resistance
HH
up

1.0667
2
0
1
buy
1.04624
1.05563
1.06501




1698148800
1.06122
1.0651
1.06497
1.06158
14720
0













1.06572











1698163200
1.05829
1.06243
1.06157
1.05866
24104
0













1.06407











1698177600
1.05844
1.05941
1.05867
1.05886
7136
0













1.0624












optimaze.py Code
from backtesting import Backtest, Strategy
from app.analyst.testanalytics import TestAnalytics
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

TestAnalytics.start(
    login=5030094614,
    password='DlCg+gH0',
    server='MetaQuotes-Demo'
)

def prepare(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0]) if isinstance(data, list) else data
    df.rename(columns={
        'time': 'Date',
        'low': 'Low',
        'high': 'High',
        'open': 'Open',
        'close': 'Close',
        'volume': 'Volume'
    }, inplace=True)
    df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
    return df

def ohlc(support_and_resistance_candleback=18, sma_candleback=20, rsi_candleback=14):
    raw_data = TestAnalytics.run(
        support_and_resistance_candleback=support_and_resistance_candleback,
        sma_candleback=sma_candleback,
        rsi_candleback=rsi_candleback
    )
    df = prepare(raw_data)
    
    required_columns = ['Date', 'Low', 'High', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume']
    df = df[required_columns]
    df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='s', errors='coerce')
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    
    numeric_columns = ['Low', 'High', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume']
    df[numeric_columns] = df[numeric_columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

    df.to_csv('_debug/ohlc.csv', index=False)
    # print(df)
    return df

def indicators(support_and_resistance_candleback=18, sma_candleback=20, rsi_candleback=14):
    raw_data = TestAnalytics.run(
        support_and_resistance_candleback=support_and_resistance_candleback,
        sma_candleback=sma_candleback,
        rsi_candleback=rsi_candleback
    )
    df = prepare(raw_data)

    required_columns = ['action', 'limit_price', 'stop_loss', 'take_profit']
    df = df[required_columns]
    df.replace('', pd.NA, inplace=True)
    numeric_columns = ['limit_price', 'stop_loss', 'take_profit']
    df[numeric_columns] = df[numeric_columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    
    if 'action' in df.columns:
        action_mapping = {'buy': 1, 'sell': -1, 'neutral': 0}
        df['action'] = df['action'].replace(action_mapping)
        for col in required_columns:
            df[col] = df[col].fillna(0)
        df['action'] = df['action'].astype(int)

    df.to_csv('_debug/indicators.csv', index=False)
    # print(df)
    return df


class LimitOrderStrategy(Strategy):
    trade_size = 1000
    support_and_resistance_candleback = 18
    sma_candleback = 20
    rsi_candleback = 14
    counter = 0

    def init(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.indicators = self.I(
            indicators, 
            self.support_and_resistance_candleback, 
            self.sma_candleback, self.rsi_candleback
            )
        np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
        indicator_array = np.array(self.indicators.data)
        # print(indicator_array)
        if indicator_array.shape[0] == 4:
            indicator_array = indicator_array.T
        if indicator_array.size > 0 and not np.all(np.isnan(indicator_array)):
            indicator_data = pd.DataFrame(
                indicator_array, 
                columns=['action', 'limit_price', 'stop_loss', 'take_profit']
                )
            indicator_data.to_csv('_debug/indicators.csv', index=False)
            # print(indicator_data)
            self.actions = indicator_data['action'].to_numpy()
            self.limit_prices = indicator_data['limit_price'].to_numpy()
            self.stop_losss = indicator_data['stop_loss'].to_numpy()
            self.take_profits = indicator_data['take_profit'].to_numpy()

            # print(self.actions)

    def next(self):
        action = int(self.actions[self.counter])
        limit_price = self.limit_prices[self.counter]
        stop_loss = self.stop_losss[self.counter]
        take_profit = self.take_profits[self.counter]
        # print(action)
        if action in [1, -1]:
            if action == 1:
                self.buy(size=self.trade_size, limit=limit_price, stop=stop_loss, tp=take_profit)
            elif action == -1:
                self.sell(size=self.trade_size, limit=limit_price, stop=stop_loss, tp=take_profit)
        self.counter += 1

def main():
    df = ohlc()
    bt = Backtest(
        df, 
        LimitOrderStrategy, 
        cash=10000, 
        commission=0.000, 
        trade_on_close=False, 
        exclusive_orders=True
    )
    stats, heatmap = bt.optimize(
        sma_candleback=range(5, 20),  
        maximize='Win Rate [%]',  
        return_heatmap=True
    )

    print(stats)
    print(heatmap)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Debugging
ohlc() return
                         Low     High     Open    Close  Volume
Date
2023-09-26 00:00:00  1.05805  1.05963  1.05928  1.05842    2786
2023-09-26 04:00:00  1.05781  1.05929  1.05841  1.05926    3077
2023-09-26 08:00:00  1.05700  1.06000  1.05926  1.05959    8667
2023-09-26 12:00:00  1.05895  1.06091  1.05960  1.06058    7775
2023-09-26 16:00:00  1.05674  1.06065  1.06058  1.05692   12413
...                      ...      ...      ...      ...     ...
2024-01-22 04:00:00  1.08979  1.09093  1.09018  1.09015   13536
2024-01-22 08:00:00  1.08871  1.09096  1.09015  1.08970   29556
2024-01-22 12:00:00  1.08797  1.08994  1.08970  1.08917   36801
2024-01-22 16:00:00  1.08816  1.09000  1.08917  1.08961   43915
2024-01-22 20:00:00  1.08801  1.08965  1.08961  1.08820   23934

[499 rows x 5 columns]

indicators() return
     action  limit_price  stop_loss  take_profit
0         0          0.0        0.0          0.0
1         0          0.0        0.0          0.0
2         0          0.0        0.0          0.0
3         0          0.0        0.0          0.0
4         0          0.0        0.0          0.0
..      ...          ...        ...          ...
494       0          0.0        0.0          0.0
495       0          0.0        0.0          0.0
496       0          0.0        0.0          0.0
497       0          0.0        0.0          0.0
498       0          0.0        0.0          0.0

[499 rows x 4 columns]

indicator_array in init()
[[ 0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       1.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.      -1.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   1.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       1.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       1.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.      -1.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       1.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.      -1.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       1.05563  0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       1.06094  0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   1.06579  0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       1.07624  0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       1.07872  0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       1.08764  0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       1.09382
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       1.09982
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
   0.       0.       0.     ]
 [...][...]]

indicator_data in init()
     action  limit_price  stop_loss  take_profit
0       0.0          0.0        0.0          0.0
1       0.0          0.0        0.0          0.0
2       0.0          0.0        0.0          0.0
3       0.0          0.0        0.0          0.0
4       0.0          0.0        0.0          0.0
..      ...          ...        ...          ...
494     0.0          0.0        0.0          0.0
495     0.0          0.0        0.0          0.0
496     0.0          0.0        0.0          0.0
497     0.0          0.0        0.0          0.0
498     0.0          0.0        0.0          0.0

[499 rows x 4 columns]

self.actions in init()
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]

action in next()
Using [-1] in next()
All values are 0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
...

Using self.counter in next()
The values are correct, but they do not update with each change in sma_candleback during optimization.
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
-1
0

Output
Using [-1] in next()
Code
action = int(self.actions[[-1]])
limit_price = self.limit_prices[[-1]]
stop_loss = self.stop_losss[[-1]]
take_profit = self.take_profits[[-1]]

Result
Start                     2023-09-26 00:00:00
End                       2024-01-22 20:00:00
Duration                    118 days 20:00:00
Exposure Time [%]                         0.0
Equity Final [$]                      10000.0
Equity Peak [$]                       10000.0
Return [%]                                0.0
Buy & Hold Return [%]                2.813628
Return (Ann.) [%]                         0.0
Volatility (Ann.) [%]                     0.0
Sharpe Ratio                              NaN
Sortino Ratio                             NaN
Calmar Ratio                              NaN
Max. Drawdown [%]                        -0.0
Avg. Drawdown [%]                         NaN
Max. Drawdown Duration                    NaN
Avg. Drawdown Duration                    NaN
# Trades                                    0
Win Rate [%]                              NaN
Best Trade [%]                            NaN
Worst Trade [%]                           NaN
Avg. Trade [%]                            NaN
Max. Trade Duration                       NaN
Avg. Trade Duration                       NaN
Profit Factor                             NaN
Expectancy [%]                            NaN
SQN                                       NaN
_strategy                 LimitOrderStrate...
_equity_curve                             ...
_trades                   Empty DataFrame
...
dtype: object
sma_candleback
1                NaN
2                NaN
3                NaN
4                NaN
5                NaN
6                NaN
7                NaN
8                NaN
9                NaN
10               NaN
11               NaN
12               NaN
13               NaN
14               NaN
15               NaN
16               NaN
17               NaN
18               NaN
19               NaN
Name: Win Rate [%], dtype: float64

Using self.counter in next()
Code
action = int(self.actions[[self.counter]])
limit_price = self.limit_prices[[self.counter]]
stop_loss = self.stop_losss[[self.counter]]
take_profit = self.take_profits[[self.counter]]

Result
Start                     2023-09-26 00:00:00
End                       2024-01-22 20:00:00
Duration                    118 days 20:00:00
Exposure Time [%]                   99.398798
Equity Final [$]                     10030.01
Equity Peak [$]                      10053.34
Return [%]                             0.3001
Buy & Hold Return [%]                2.813628
Return (Ann.) [%]                    0.975993
Volatility (Ann.) [%]                0.786113
Sharpe Ratio                         1.241542
Sortino Ratio                        1.970413
Calmar Ratio                         3.542233
Max. Drawdown [%]                    -0.27553
Avg. Drawdown [%]                   -0.069088
Max. Drawdown Duration       25 days 12:00:00
Avg. Drawdown Duration        5 days 18:00:00
# Trades                                    1
Win Rate [%]                            100.0
Best Trade [%]                       2.832201
Worst Trade [%]                      2.832201
Avg. Trade [%]                       2.832201
Max. Trade Duration         118 days 08:00:00
Avg. Trade Duration         118 days 08:00:00
Profit Factor                             NaN
Expectancy [%]                       2.832201
SQN                                       NaN
_strategy                 LimitOrderStrate...
_equity_curve                             ...
_trades                      Size  EntryBa...
dtype: object
sma_candleback
1                 100.0
2                 100.0
3                 100.0
4                 100.0
5                 100.0
6                 100.0
7                 100.0
8                 100.0
9                 100.0
10                100.0
11                100.0
12                100.0
13                100.0
14                100.0
15                100.0
16                100.0
17                100.0
18                100.0
19                100.0
Name: Win Rate [%], dtype: float64

Other attempts

I tried assigning the data to sefla.data in init(), but it doesn't work because the library takes the data only at the first initialization, not during every optimization loop.

I'm trying to use self.counter but I think it's not working.


Goal
I want to optimize my strategies and indicators.

I have similar problem. And I also tried myself self.counter. However, be careful. Proper usage is self.data.index[-1], which is = self.counter+1. It is an index of your input_df. I recommend to reset index before input to Backtest(): input_df.reset_index(inplace=True). Second. Instead of this:
self.actions = indicator_data['action'].to_numpy()
use this:
self.actions = self.I(lambda x: x, indicator_data['action'].to_numpy(), plot=False).
PS. I do not put it into answers, because I am not 100% sure if it solves your problem.
